# How Can I Pass var between pages in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I pass var between pages in C# WPF. For example I have my int in Page1.xaml.cs and how can I pass this var to Page1.xaml.cs

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```
int var = 1;
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            How can I after press button send var to page2
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean, pass to `Page2.xaml.cs1`

Comment: Usually both pages would share the same DataContext. When both pages bind to the same DataContext, then they can share data very easily e.g. by updating a property on the data source. Simply define a data object, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and assign a shared instance to the DataContext of both pages. Then define a DependencyProperty on each page and bind them to the same property (TwoWay) on the object instance assigned to the DataContext. Now when a page updates it's property, it will update the property on the DataContext, which will then update the property of the second page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int var = 1;
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page2(var);
    }
```

In page 2 you will need something to pass in var

```
public Page2(int var)
{

}
```

Comment: How's that even going to compile?

Answer (score -2):

It depends on how the Pages are related. For example

When `Page1` creates `Page2`, I would pass the `var` variable via the constructor of `Page2`. If you need to call some  methods, you can't add it there.

If `Page1` and `Page2` don't share any relation, the most easiest is a singleton (static) instance, which could be accessed by both, **but** it would be hard to make tests for. There are some better implementations like `Dependency Injection` which is more testfriendly. Start at the beginning.

Comment: You would use data binding and DataContext to achieve the goal. No need for Singleton here.

Comment: I didn't thought about the DataContext. It would be a great option, but when reading the question, it might be too complication for now.

Comment: That's funny. You consider data binding to complicated, but then recommend dependency injection.

Comment: You're right, DI is much tougher. He should stick at passing it via the constructor.

Comment: I probably would go for binding.